# Is the clang static analyzer confused by popping the front from a list of unique_ptrs?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang-static-analyzer, false-positive

The following C++11 code is a minimal example of what I believe triggers a false positive in clang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

class ElementType {};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<ElementType>> theList(5);

    theList.pop_front();

    for (const auto &element: theList) { // (*)
        std::cout << "This should be fine." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On the line marked by an asterisk (*), the clang analyzer claims

> > *...filePath...*/main.cpp:21:29: Use of memory after it is freed (within a call to 'begin')

As far as I interpret it, this code is harmless, but clang misses the point that `std::list<T>::pop_front()` not only calls its elements' destructor, but that it also moves the location of `std::list<T>::begin()`. Replacing the call to `pop_front` by `pop_back` makes the analyzer warning disappear, and even replacing it by `erase(theList.begin())` makes it come out warning-free.

Am I missing something or did I actually stumble upon a missed case in clang?

For reference:
These results come from XCode 5.1.1 (5B1008) on Mac OS X 10.9.2,

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: You should report this as a false positive. Not sure what the question here really is... the code is (obviously?) fine.

Comment: This is the question "Am I missing something or did I actually stumble upon a missed case in clang?"

Comment: Actually, as this errors occurs to me using `libc++` but not using GNU's `libstdc++` (as of `clang-3.5` and `gcc-4.9` respectively in 64-bits Debian) it may very well be a bug in `libc++`.

Comment: @Massa Oh, interesting hypothesis. I can't reproduce this though, my `libstdc++` doesn't offer C++11 support. But I'll add this information to the bug-report on the Bugzilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been acknowledged to be a bug by the LLVM team.

In a [comment on Revision 211832](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=211832) it is stated that since

> [*t*]he analyzer cannot reason about the internal invariances of [*containers
>   such as std::vector and std::list*] which leads to false positives

the analyzer should

> just not inline the methods of the containers and allow objects to
>   escape whenever such methods are called.

The issue is indeed no longer reproducible on XCode  6.4 (6E35b) with

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 5):

The code, as it stands, looks fine.

I check the code [from libc++](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/list) (relevant parts) and I believe that it just confuses the static analyzer.

In more details:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Alloc>
void list<_Tp, _Alloc>::pop_front()
{
    _LIBCPP_ASSERT(!empty(), "list::pop_front() called with empty list");
    __node_allocator& __na = base::__node_alloc();
    __node_pointer __n = base::__end_.__next_;
    base::__unlink_nodes(__n, __n);
    --base::__sz();
    __node_alloc_traits::destroy(__na, _VSTD::addressof(__n->__value_));
    __node_alloc_traits::deallocate(__na, __n, 1);
}
```

`list` is implemented as a circular list, based at `__end_` (which is the end-pointer), so to get to the first element, the code goes to `__end_.__next_`.

The implementation of `__unlink_nodes` is:

```
// Unlink nodes [__f, __l]
template <class _Tp, class _Alloc>
inline void __list_imp<_Tp, _Alloc>::__unlink_nodes(__node_pointer __f,
                                                    __node_pointer __l) noexcept
{
    __f->__prev_->__next_ = __l->__next_;
    __l->__next_->__prev_ = __f->__prev_;
}
```

We can easily understand it with some simple ASCII art:

```
       Z             A             B             C
  +---------+   +---------+   +---------+   +---------+
--| __prev_ |<--| __prev_ |<--| __prev_ |<--| __prev_ |<-
->| __next_ |-->| __next_ |-->| __next_ |-->| __next_ |--
  +---------+   +---------+   +---------+   +---------+
```

To remove the range `A`-`B` from this list:

- `Z.__next_` has to point to `C`
- `C.__prev_` has to point to `Z`

Thus the call `__unlink_nodes(A, B)` will:

- take `A.__prev_.__next_` (ie, `Z.__next_`) and make it point to `B.__next_` (ie, `C`)
- take `B.__next_.__prev_` (ie, `C.__prev_`) and make it point to `A.__prev_` (ie, `Z`)

This is simple, and works even when invoked with a single element-range (the case here).

Now, however, note that if the `list` were to be empty, this would not work at all! The default constructor of `__list_node_base` is:

```
__list_node_base()
    : __prev_(static_cast<pointer>(pointer_traits<__base_pointer>::pointer_to(*this))),
      __next_(static_cast<pointer>(pointer_traits<__base_pointer>::pointer_to(*this)))
      {}
```

That is, it refers to itself. In this case, `__unlink_nodes` is invoked with `&__end_` (twice), and would not change it `__end_.__prev_.__next_ = __end_.__next_` is idempotent (because `__end_.prev` is `__end_` itself).

It may be that:

- the analyzer takes into account the case of an empty list (`_LIBCPP_ASSERT` being compiled out)
- and concludes that in this case, the `__end_.__next_` (used by `begin()`) is left dangling by the `deallocate()` call in `pop_front()`

Or maybe it's something else in the pointer dance... hopefully the Clang team will be able to patch things up.